# Add href link in custom grid in webform ASP.NET and Get ID of Select Row using JQuery

Tags: webforms, custom-controls, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to add  inside custom grid within template but I cannot see these links in output along with other grid data ....

```
<cc0:Grid ID="StaffItemList" runat="server" FolderStyle="~/Styles/Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                     Width="100%" PageSizeOptions="5,10,20,50,100,-1" AllowFiltering="true" FilterType="ProgrammaticOnly"
                     AllowAddingRecords="false">
        <Columns>
         <cc0:CheckBoxSelectColumn ShowHeaderCheckBox="true" Width="50" ControlStyle-CssClass="UserInRoleGrid"></cc0:CheckBoxSelectColumn>
         <cc0:Column DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="true" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="loginid" HeaderText="loginid" Width="150" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="forenames" HeaderText="forenames" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="surnames" HeaderText="surnames" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="email" HeaderText="email" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="deleted" HeaderText="deleted" />     
        </Columns>
        <Templates>
         <cc0:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="AddUserToRoleLink">
           <Template>
             <a href="#" class="AddUserToRoleClass"> addRole</a>                              
           </Template>
          </cc0:GridTemplate>
       </Templates>
</cc0:Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found asnswer; code as following....

```
<cc0:Grid ID="StaffItemList" runat="server" FolderStyle="~/Styles/Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                     Width="100%" PageSizeOptions="5,10,20,50,100,-1" AllowFiltering="true" FilterType="ProgrammaticOnly"
                     AllowAddingRecords="false">
   <Columns>
         <cc0:Column DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="true"/>
         <cc0:Column DataField="loginid" HeaderText="loginid" Width="150" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="forenames" HeaderText="forenames" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="surnames" HeaderText="surnames" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="email" HeaderText="email" />
         <cc0:Column DataField="deleted" HeaderText="deleted" />     
         <cc0:Column DataField="Functions" HeaderText="deleted" >
              <TemplateSettings TemplateId="AddUserToRoleControl"/>
          </cc0:Column> 
        </Columns>
        <Templates>
           <cc0:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="AddUserToRoleControl">
         <Template>
                 <a href="#" id="<%# Container.DataItem["id"] %>" class="AddStaffToRoleLink"> Add Role</a>
         </Template>
           </cc0:GridTemplate>
   </Templates>
</cc0:Grid>
```

### jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $(".AddStaffToRoleLink").on("click", function () {

           var selectedStaffID = $(this).attr("id");

           alert("this is " + selectedStaffID);
       });

   });
</script>
```